# Pass values from popup to parent

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I want to get the Facebook authorization code to be passed to a server. The way I am planning to go about it is as follows (let me know if theres a better way):

- Open a popup to do FB login
- (Popup) FB will redirect user to site with authorization code. I will get this code to pass to parent window.

But the thing is how do I do this? The message passing part? Theres postMessage but thats not supported in older browsers? So is there a better way? Also parent window is an Angular app, so it will be harder to do `window.parent.someFunction`

Comment: Dunno if this is helpful, do you want to do passing to the server from the popup window and on success, child window changes URL of the parent and closes itself?

Comment: @KannanJ, that works too

Comment: Thanks I have posted this as answer. You can accept it if it is ok. Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

It is better to avoid passing token code to parent window because the authorisation popup should complete the full lifecycle and return. Also it is good to expose the auth tokens to have increased security.

One workable option would be to have the popup window do the server side call and on on success, child window changes URL of the parent and closes itself.